# Set folder permissions when creating folder - nodejs

Tags: development, document-library, permissions

I have a document library with several folders for different projects. I have projectConsultant user who has read & write permissions to all these folders. There is also projectClient who has view permissions to all the folders. projectClient can call an api to upload files to a folder called clientFolder. If clientFolder doesn't exist, then it is created and permissions are set so that projectClient has read & write permissions and projectConsultant will only have read permissions.

How do I go about setting these permissions when the clientFolder is created?
I have been looking for a npm library but haven't found anything relevant.

Comment: Found pnp/sp/sharing package. Going to be working around with this and see if it works out.

Comment: edit: pnp/sp/sharing did not help